# How to check third party chrome extension in chrome developer console using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want to capture the chrome third party plugin names if installed in the browser, for example, I have installed Grammarly, adblocker, etc. For some business purpose I need to get the list of plugins using javascript in the chrome developer console itself. Is that possible to capture the third party plugin names?

Thanks

Comment: You can use [chrome.management API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management) from an extension.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically you can use `chrome.management.getAll()` which retrieves an array of `ExtensionInfo` objects, one for each installed extension and app. You can distinguish apps from extensions using the `type` property of `ExtensionInfo`.

This API requires the `management` permission.